# How to read a .drw file in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, file, user-interface

I have been practising reading `.txt` files from locations and manipulating them but I have come across a new format called `.drw` and need help with reading the contents of it in `Java`.

I have managed to load the `.drw` file into a `File` object as seen below but now need help retrieving the contents:

```
File file = new File("/src/random.drw"); //throws DataFormat Exception
```

For the example's sake, please assume that the file contains `Point` objects

Comment: the way you read the file, depends on its structure. every file is a sequence of bytes

Comment: Please see my edit, does that make it clear?

Comment: could you post the full message of exception

Comment: @mangusta I dont get an exception, I just dont know how to read the file.

Comment: if the file consists of objects, then you should deserialize them. have a look here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-an-object-from-file-in-java/

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc441433(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: A .drw file is a Micrografx Designer vector graphics file.  I can't find any documentation on that format, and considering no open source product seems to be able to read them, I'm guessing no one else has found the documentation either.  Without that documentation, you can't write code to read information from the file.